# how to create PieChartFX for each row in TableView when selected by mouse?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8, pie-chart

how to pass data from Table-view in javaFX  to PieChartFX

i want to show same row values into my pie-chart when selected  by mouse MOUSE_RELEASED ?

i want to insert data to PieChartFX  for each row, whenever the specific row is selected by mouse click or MOUSE RELEASED ?

this is my code

```
    package javaapplication26;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class JavaFXjavaapplication26_TableView extends Application {

     public TableView < Metrics > tableView = new TableView<Metrics>();
    private ObservableList< Metrics > dataList =   FXCollections.observableArrayList(

    // /do something like this  new Metrics(name,WMC,DIT,NOC ,CBO,RFC,LCOM , Ce, NPM),
    // i want to add Metrics ADDED DYNAMICALLY after file is parsed

    );

             ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =   FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("WMC", 100),
                    new PieChart.Data("DIT", 200),
                    new PieChart.Data("NOC", 50),
                    new PieChart.Data("CBO", 75),
                    new PieChart.Data("RFC", 110),
                    new PieChart.Data("LCOM", 300),
                    new PieChart.Data("Ca", 111),
                    new PieChart.Data("NPM", 30)

                );

      PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);





      public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
      }

      @Override
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


          primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
          Group root = new Group();

          TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
                    name.setCellValueFactory(          new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, String>("name"));


        TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
                    WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(    new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("WMC"));

        TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
       DITCol.setCellValueFactory(        new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("DIT"));

        TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
        NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(             new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("NOC"));
        TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
           CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(          new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("CBO"));
        TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
           RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(        new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("RFC"));
        TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
        LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(             new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("LCOM"));
        TableColumn ceCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
       ceCol.setCellValueFactory(          new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("ce"));
        TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
        NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(        new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>("NPM"));





          tableView.setItems(dataList);
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(name,WMCCol,DITCol,NOCCol,CBOCol,RFCCol,LCOMCol,ceCol,NPMCol);

          // PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
            VBox vBox = new VBox();
          vBox.setSpacing(10);

          vBox.getChildren().add(pieChart);
          vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);
          root.getChildren().add(vBox);

          primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 900));
          primaryStage.show();

          List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\11.txt");
         // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
         tableView.getItems().addAll(metric) ;
         //    pieChart.getItems().addAll(metric) ;
         // ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =   FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        for (Metrics m : metric) {      
       //  System.out.println(m);     

     }

      }


      public List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {

      List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();
      //    tableView.getItems().addAll(metricsss);
      Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
      // create an instance of BufferedReader
      // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources 
      try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,                StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
    br.readLine();
    String line1=null;
    // read the first line from the text file
    String line = br.readLine();                 
    while (line != null) { // loop until all lines are read                      
    String[] attributes = line.split(" ");  // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
    Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);
    metricsss.add(valueOfMetric);      // adding metric  into ArrayList
    //skip empty line 
    // line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().equals("\n"))
    br.readLine();
    line = br.readLine();
          }

      } catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
      }

                    return metricsss;
      }

      private   Metrics createMetric(String[] metadata) {
        String name = metadata[0];
        int WMC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1]);
        int DIT = Integer.parseInt(metadata[2]);
        int NOC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[3]);
        int CBO = Integer.parseInt(metadata[4]);
        int RFC = Integer.parseInt(metadata[5]);
        int LCOM= Integer.parseInt(metadata[6]);
        int Ce  = Integer.parseInt(metadata[7]);
        int NPM = Integer.parseInt(metadata[8]);
        return new Metrics(name,WMC,DIT,NOC,CBO,RFC,LCOM,Ce,NPM);//,cc
    }


      public class Metrics {

        private String name;
        private int WMC;
        private int DIT;
        private int NOC;
        private int CBO;
        private int RFC;
        private int LCOM;
        private int Ce;
        private int NPM;

        public Metrics( String name,int WMC,int DIT,int NOC,int CBO,int RFC,int LCOM, int Ce, int NPM) {

            this.name = name;
            this.WMC = WMC;
            this.DIT = DIT;
            this.NOC = NOC;
            this.CBO = CBO;
            this.RFC = RFC;
            this.LCOM = LCOM;
            this.Ce = Ce;
            this.NPM = NPM;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getWMC() {
            return WMC;
        }

        public void setWMC(int WMC) {
            this.WMC = WMC;
        }

        public int getDIT() {
            return DIT;
        }

        public void setDIT(int DIT) {
            this.DIT = DIT;
        }

        public int getNOC() {
            return NOC;
        }

        public void setNOC(int NOC) {
            this.NOC = NOC;
        }

        public int getCBO() {
            return CBO;
        }

        public void setCBO(int CBO) {
            this.CBO = CBO;
        }

        public int getRFC() {
            return RFC;
        }

        public void setRFC(int RFC) {
            this.RFC = RFC;
        }

        public int getLCOM() {
            return LCOM;
        }

        public void setLCOM(int LCOM) {
            this.LCOM = LCOM;
        }

        public int getCe() {
            return Ce;
        }

        public void setCe(int ce) {
            Ce = ce;
        }

        public int getNPM() {
            return NPM;
        }

        public void setNPM(int NPM) {
            this.NPM = NPM;
        }


    }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[Pie Chart java example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm#CIHFDADD)

```
tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));//added
```

I have added above line of code to create observaleList using list

```
 br.readLine();//removed here this read extraline 
String line1=null;
// read the first line from the text file
String line = br.readLine();                 
while (line != null) {
```

above condition is worng what if line is empty ? I have changed this too.(sorry for not explaing I dont know that much english)

```
    @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
    Group root = new Group();

    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("name");
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, String>(
            "name"));

    TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
    WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "WMC"));

    TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
    DITCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "DIT"));

    TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
    NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "NOC"));
    TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
    CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "CBO"));
    TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
    RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "RFC"));
    TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
    LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "LCOM"));
    TableColumn ceCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
    ceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "ce"));
    TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
    NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Metrics, Double>(
            "NPM"));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
    primaryStage.show();

    List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\pavi\\Desktop\\11.txt");
    // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
    for (Metrics m : metric) {
        System.out.println(m);

    }

    tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(metric));
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(name, WMCCol, DITCol, NOCCol, CBOCol,
            RFCCol, LCOMCol, ceCol, NPMCol);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setMaxSize(600, 600);
    vBox.setSpacing(10);
    PieChart c = new PieChart();
    tableView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            c.setData(FXCollections.emptyObservableList());
            TableViewSelectionModel<Metrics> tableViewSelectionModel = tableView
                    .selectionModelProperty().get();
            Metrics m = tableViewSelectionModel.getSelectedItem();
            if(m==null){
                return;
            }
            ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList(
                            new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                            new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                            new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                            new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
            c.setData(pieChartData);
        }
    });
    vBox.getChildren().add(tableView);
    vBox.getChildren().add(c);

    root.getChildren().add(vBox);

}

public List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {

    List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();

    Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);
    // create an instance of BufferedReader
    // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
            StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
        // read the first line from the text file
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) { // loop until all lines
                                                    // are read
            String[] attributes = line.split(" "); // the file, using a
                                                    // comma as the
                                                    // delimiter
            Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);
            metricsss.add(valueOfMetric); // adding metric into ArrayList
            // skip empty line
            // line.isEmpty() || line.trim().equals("") ||
            // line.trim().equals("\n"))
            br.readLine();
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return metricsss;
}
```

for charts we need create data set to pieChart.setData(pieChartData);
Reff the like bellow image you ll understand

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
                    .observableArrayList(
                            new PieChart.Data("CBO", m.getCBO()),
                            new PieChart.Data("Ce", m.getCe()),
                            new PieChart.Data("DIT", m.getDIT()),
                            new PieChart.Data("LCOM", m.getLCOM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NOC", m.getNOC()),
                            new PieChart.Data("NPM", m.getNPM()),
                            new PieChart.Data("WMC", m.getWMC()));
            c.setData(pieChartData);
```